# Using header (.h) files with cpp files in an R Package with Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using 3rd party header files with Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995266/using-3rd-party-header-files-with-rcpp)

*Note: This is a continuation of a discussion started here: 
[Using 3rd party header files with Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995266/using-3rd-party-header-files-with-rcpp). However, the question is different enough that I thought I would pose it as its own question.*

I have a header file called `coolStuff.h` that contains a function `awesomeSauce(arg1)` that I would like to call in the cpp files that are in my R package.

Package Structure:

- packageName

  - DESCRIPTION
  - [man]
  - NAMESPACE
  - R

    - someRscript.R
  - src

    - theCppFile.cpp
    - otherCppFile.cpp

The Code for theCppFile.cpp:

```
`#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double someFunctionCpp(double someInput){

 double someOutput = awesomeSauce(someInput);

return someOutput;`
```

1) Where should I place `coolStuff.h` in the package directory structure so that when the package is built, and the cpp files are compiled, the code from coolStuff.h will be included.

2) How should I call this file in the `coolStuff.h`?

3) Similarly, if I want to call `otherCppFile.cpp` in `theCppFile.cpp` where do

Thanks again for your help. I learned a lot from the last conversation. If there is standard documentation for some of this somewhere I'll be happy to RTFM, just point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

There *is an entire vignette devoted to building a package with Rcpp* and yes, you should look at it.

Rcpp attributes are indeed fantastic for quick and simple things, but even they rely on packages:  you couldn't do their Depends: on, say, RcppArmadillo if it weren't for the inline plugin provided by the RcppArmadillo package.

So in short: yes, do read the fine manual and/or look at (currently) 95 packages on CRAN that use Rcpp and Depends on it.

*Edit:*  There is one possible short-cut here:  if `coolStuff.h` is just a header (so no linking to external libraries) you can get by using it in the same directory as your source. That helps with quick `sourceCpp()` exploration. But to to a *package* you still need to do extra steps, but even some of those have been automated---see the Rcpp attributes vignette.

*Edit 2*: I just re-read your previous question. This **new question makes no sense** and adds nothing.  Did you read and understand what we told you last time?

Comment: Thanks Dirk I will take a look at that and see if I can make heads or tails of it. I have found that some of the Rcpp documentation assumes I know a lot more about C++ than I do, and for that matter a lot more about the deeper internals of R and Rcpp than I do.

Comment: It's complicated. We try our hardest to make some things easy, but we can do that for all things.  You still need to read up on a few things, and package creation is among them. Or use the worked examples --- see eg the hint I just added to my answer.

Comment: OK I guess this was not different enough to be its own question. I will continue on the original question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995266/using-3rd-party-header-files-with-rcpp